# arithmetic in hex in C

Tags: c, math, hex

is there a way to do arithmetic in hex in c? Also comparisons between two hex numbers, how would you do that?  I haven't seen any good examples of this, if you have one that would be a big help!

Comment: A number is a number. The base is just a formatting concern.

Comment: Would you be storing the hex as a string?

Comment: If not, then what Mitch said.

Comment: i can store them as int, ok, i will experiment

Comment: Not if you are an alien with 16 fingers, Mitch. :)

Comment: i guess you need to do int = 0xA; i see now.

Comment: Comparisons are *easy* in any base. You just have to know the ordering of the digits and that you are using a positional representation. You use exactly the same algorithm you use for comparing base 10 numbers (excepting that you have 6 nifty new digits to play with).

Answer (score 2):

You can just do it directly. Numbers are just numbers. Base is simply a representation of a number.

```
int x = 0xa - 0x3;
printf("%02x\n", x);
```

You can mix formatting for bases too, as they all get represented the same internally to the computer.

```
// 0 in front for octal
// 0x in front for hexadecimal
x = 2*19 - 023 - 0x13; // x is now 0, as 19 == 023 == 0x13
```

Printing them with the base you want is simply a matter of picking the formatting:

```
x = 023; // 0x13
printf("%02d\n", x); // Format as decimal
printf("%02o\n", x); // Format as octal
printf("%02x\n", x); // Format as hexadecimal
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the defining characteristics of math is that 6 * 7 = 42; VI * VII = XLII; 110b * 111b = 101010b. When your computer does the math, it doesn't matter how the processor represents the number. The base only matters when it displays the number to you, the user.

Comment: You're not answering : The question is about the syntax of a specific programming language, not about the ability of a computing machine to compute

Answer (score 0):

"Hex" is only a notational convention for numbers (as is "decimal"). There is no "hex arithmetic, in addition to the usual version".

That is, 10+16 is 26, *even if* you write the numbers down as `0x0A + 0x10` -- and the answer in hex would be `0x1A` (which *also* is '26', fortunately).

There is no need to provide separate ways for comparing hex numbers either -- as said in the comments, a number is a *number*; not "hex number" or "octal number". Try this, using your favourite compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
  printf ("10 + 16 = %d\n", 10 + 16);
  printf ("0xa + 0x10 = %x\n", 0xa + 0x10);
  printf ("012 + 020 = %o\n", 012 + 020);
  printf ("10 = 0xa? %d\n", 10 == 0xa);
  printf ("10 = 0x10? %d\n", 10 == 0x10);
  return 0;
}
```